# Converting pitches in audio to MIDI

Tags: midi, logic

I want to hum a tune and have the notes be converted into MIDI notes… is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible. Here’s how to do it in Logic Pro X (where it’s different from earlier versions):

1. record an audio clip to an audio track
2. double-click the clip to view it in the Editor panel
3. click the Show/Hide Flex button near the top left of the editor window, to the right of the menus

   [image: Show/Hide Flex button at the top left of the Editor in Logic Pro X]
4. You will be asked ‘Do you want to turn on Flex for track “Audio 1”?’. Confirm “Turn on Flex”.
5. change the Flex pop-up menu at the top of the Editor from “Flex Time – Automatic (Slicing)” to “Flex Pitch”
6. right-click the audio area and choose “Set all to Perfect Pitch”

   [image: “Set all to Perfect Pitch” in the Flex Pitch editor’s context menu]
7. from the Edit menu of the Editor area, choose “Create MIDI Track from Flex Pitch Data”, at the bottom

   [image: “Create MIDI Track from Flex Pitch Data” in the Edit menu in the Flex Pitch editor]

This will generate a MIDI region with the notes Logic can detect from your audio. You can delete your audio track now.

[image: generated MIDI track below the original audio track]

You will probably want to quantize your notes too, which makes notes start on the beat. You can do this by viewing the generated MIDI region in the Editor panel, selecting all of the notes, and choosing a beat size in Time Quantize at the left. Or you could do it earlier in the process, with the Time Quantize section next to the Flex Pitch editor.

[image: Time Quantize in the Editor panel when editing the generated MIDI region]

Comment: can you do it directly without having to record? as soon as I hum a song it goes straight to midi. thank you

Comment: @MarcoAlexandre Sorry, I don’t think Logic Pro X supports any simpler way. At best, you could write a script in [SikuliX](http://www.sikuli.org/) that would automate the steps above by pressing keys and clicking for you. (You couldn’t write such a script with [AppleScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript) because Logic Pro X doesn’t expose the necessary functions in its Scripting Dictionary.)

Comment: I've been doing that kind of thing in Digital Performer using Melodyne for a few years. I just started getting in Logic and tried the method described by Rory O'Kane. In my case it's getting things I play on guitar turned into MIDI so that I can create bass lines and so on with a regular six string guitar. The way to do it in Logic is much quicker and more straightforward than the method I've been using in DP. Thanks Rory!
Now to see if it can do it polyphonically like Melodyne can. I've played piano parts on guitar that way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Logic installed right now, but it should have something like that built in. Just select Audio to Score… from the context menu for an audio clip, see [Advanced Functions in Logic Pro 8 : How to Use Factory Audio to Score in Logic Pro 8](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paklcuY0Zqk).